# How to auto increment a value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

How to create **alphanumeric** auto_increment with a prefix which will be inserted into a table whenever a procedure is called and the procedure will return that value? The datatype can be number or varchar.

**For Example**:

```
M0000001
M0000002
M0000003
....
M0000011
```

Comment: Why can't you just use an auto increment column and then tag on the letter `M` or whatever alpha sequence you want?

Comment: If you are new to SQL, don't try to figure this out.  Learn to use and love a numeric auto increment column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concat `'M'` string with your column.

```
SELECT 'M'|| num1 from test;
```

**Edited===**

Below procedure will give you last id inserted in your table.

```
create procedure return_value(IN p_col1 VARCHAR(255), IN p_col2 VARCHAR(255), OUT id VARCHAR(255))
begin
    insert into test(col1,col2) values(p_col1,p_col2);
    SELECT 'M'|| max(num1) into id from test;
end;
```

Comment: @steve you need procedure that return the value ? but which value ?

Comment: @steve what do you mean by current value ? you mean last value ?

Comment: @steve check my post and hope, you are expecting same

Comment: @steve man,you need complete code ? it was very simple . right ? you can just right the insert statement just before select ?

Comment: ya ravi i need complete code .. Because currently i'm messed up with other things ... Did nt able to think how it should be done!!

Comment: @steve Ok, I will give you sample code, you need to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
);
```